# Sequelize Migration - Create Trigger in PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, database-trigger

I need to create Trigger on one of my Table using Sequelize Migration in Node and PostgreSQL.
I haven't found enough documentation around it.

Currently I am using sequelize version 3.23 and quite familiar with PostgreSQL triggers, but not able to find anything around migration of triggers.

I am following docs provided on sequelize site related to migrations:

```
  module.exports = {
  up: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    // create trigger
  },

  down: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    // remove trigger
  }
}
```

Hope I get quick resolution around it..
Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 6):

You can add the triggers to your models, they're not called triggers in your sequelize models though they're called [`Hooks`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/hooks/#declaring-hooks).

Using hooks is probably a better idea since you can integrate them with your models and create actual model instances but if you really want to use postgres triggers then you can use `Sequelize.query()` like so:

```
module.exports = {
  up: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    queryInterface.sequelize.query('CREATE TRIGGER...')
  },

  down: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    queryInterface.sequelize.query('DROP TRIGGER...')
  }
}
```