# How to insert stored functions and triggers in a Postgres container

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, stored-functions, postgresql-triggers

I have a containerized Postgres database and I am trying to create a function and a trigger: a simple notification on a new row insertion.

It may seem stupid but I am unable to find how to write the code, where should I push it to the Postgres container, and how to programmatically insert the code inside the container.

I can see the following file structure

```sh
Database/Schemas/public/
|---tables
|  |___requests (tablename)
|  |__Triggers
|
|___Functions
```

I only (vaguely) found a way to copy the code inside when using the **/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/** folder (a COPY in the Dockerfile).

This injection works only - as per the Docker/Postgres documentation - when a database is created. This means I have to drop and recreate the database. This is wrong as I can't make any change to a production database.

Furthermore, when I adjoin the other SQL commands to the CREATE TABLE command in the **.sql** file, then the order of execution of these commands leads to errors (unknown table...).

My `init.sql`file programmatically copied into the **/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/** folder is:

```sql
-- init_table.sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.requests (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    ...,
);

-- create_function_notify.sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION notify_insert() RETURNS trigger AS
$$
   BEGIN
      PERFORM pg_notify('new_notif', row_to_json(NEW)::text);
      RETURN NEW;
   END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


-- create_trigger_new_event.sql
CREATE TRIGGER new_event
   AFTER INSERT
   ON public.requests
   FOR EACH ROW
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE notify_insert();

LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I also tried a "sh" version (dixit PG docs) without success: it throws an error around "$$".

```sh
#/bin/sh

set -e

psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname "$POSTGRES_DB" <<-EOSQL
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION notify_insert() RETURNS trigger AS
$$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
EOSQL
```

Comment: "*This injection works only when a database is created. This is wrong as I can't make any change to a production database.*" - to do that, you'll need some database migration tool. And it doesn't matter whether it runs inside the same docker container as the database or not.

Comment: "*When I adjoin the other SQL commands to the CREATE TABLE command in the .sql file, then the order of execution of these commands leads to errors (unknown table...)*" - nah, that should work. What is the exact error message? Notice you have a stray `LANGUAGE plpgsql;` in your sample snippet.

Comment: Indeed, in the ".sql" file, for the function, I changed the place to the `LANGUAGE plpgsql`, and removed the useless one for the trigger. To check, I opened a port on the container, used Dbeaver and I can see the trigger attached to the table, and the function.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the database migration tool? Do you mean eg Sequelize for Node.js and ActiveRecord for Rails? How is this linked?

Comment: There are many. Some dedicated tools, some built into frameworks or ORM libraries.

Comment: Thank you. Now I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41339056/sequelize-migration-create-trigger-in-postgresql

Answer (score 1):

[image]

A Dockerfile instruction `COPY ./pg_notify.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` sets up the desired trigger and notification related function to the containerized Postgres database (on creation only).

Following Bergi's remark, the correct code is:

```sql
-- pg_notify.sql

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.requests (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    app varchar,
    url varchar,
    ip varchar,
    host varchar,
    req_at VARCHAR,
    d BIGINT
);


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION notify_insert() RETURNS trigger 
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
   BEGIN
      PERFORM pg_notify('new_notification', row_to_json(NEW)::text);
      RETURN NEW;
   END;
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER new_event
   AFTER INSERT
   ON requests
   FOR EACH ROW
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE notify_insert();
```